# My cat hisses and starts screaming at me wherever we make eye contact

Tags: cats

Let me sum it up, so yesterday my wife taked our cat into the garden and started playing with it, as I come back from work I decided to come into the house from the garden side , cat noticed me , as I entered the garden she started yelling loudly out of control and started attacking me , as I went in I left it 2 hours with food and water to cool down, not long after that she started playing with me for about 1H, gave him threats , all was good again, up untill we made eye contact again then he immediately started screaming in fear I think,I never touched him, any solution?

Comment: Any sudden behavioral change should be addressed by a vet asap.

Comment: Was "threats" supposed to be "treats"?